# How to make an exe run without the IO window (command line window)?

Tags: c++, c, windows, cmd, executable

I'm trying to write an exe that runs with out any window how cat I do that?
How can I run/write an exe that will not open any window?

(A code example can be very useful).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try writing a simple cli program

Comment: are you trying to install a windows service? Have a look at procrun.

Answer (score -4):

You'll find a lot on google, for example
https://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background

So to answer this shortly, just use the windows command "start" with the parameter B (-> background i suppose).
So write your program and create a small .bat file which includes just

```
start /B <your program>
```

Comment: You can also open a program subfolder and create a "shortcut" with the command line you need.

Comment: This answers a different question than the one asked.

Comment: Why does thes answer a different question? If you write a simple program w/o GUI (Cli /winapi stuff) it will always need to be run inside a console. So why should windows know to start it "silent" if you don't tell it? If it should run as a service or autostart, there are other possibilities, of course..

Comment: If you link your program as a GUI application, it doesn't need to run in a console, and it doesn't need to present a GUI either.